# Solving for a Partial Derivative with Cramer's Rule

Tags: partial-derivative

In *Advanced Calculus* by Widder I have come across a problem on page 30 regarding Cramer's rule and solving for a partial derivative.

I understand the following:

\begin{align}
F\left(u,v,g\left(u,v,x\right)\right)&=0,\tag{1}\\
G\left(u,v,h\left(u,v,y\right)\right)&=0,\tag{2}
\end{align}
so in differentiating $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ we arive at
\begin{align}
\begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\require{cancel}\xcancel{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}}\right]=0\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial h}\left[\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\require{cancel}\xcancel{\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}}\right]=0 \end{cases}\tag{3}\\
\implies\begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right]=0,\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial h}\left[\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right]=0. \end{cases}\tag{4}
\end{align}
This makes total sense as it's really just an extension of the chain rule. But now, how do I solve for $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ using $\left(4\right)$ above? In other words, what will the coefficients be in the determinants given that I now have a chain rule? Why will they be the partial derivatives of $F$ and $G$ as he has written on the next page to give us
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial G}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}
& \displaystyle\frac{\partial G}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix},\tag{5}
\end{align}
which like the Wronskian, $\neq 0$. Is it always just the coefficients out front of any partial derivative or term with respect to $y$?

Comment: If you just set $X=\partial u/\partial y$ and $Y=\partial v/\partial y$ and collect terms containing $X$ and $Y$ on the left-hand side, and other terms on the right-hand side, you will get a system of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} e \\ f \end{pmatrix}$, where the $2 \times 2$ matrix is the one you have in (5).